# MongoDb double find on update query

Tags: mongodb, crud, mongodb-query

I finded a data my mongodb database. I want be update a array's field this data.
My data is here:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8447715/

I want will find this data and update home adress. I am trying:

```
$Data = array(
                    '$set' => array(
                        'address.name' => 'home'
                )
                ); <br>
$users->update(array('username' => 'micheal', 'address.name' => 'hame') ,$Data);
```

What's wrong ?
My english is bad,sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `$` operator to update the address that matches the selection;

```
$Data = array(
    '$set' => array(
        'address.$.name' => 'home'
    )
);
$users->update(array('username' => 'micheal', 'address.name' => 'hame') ,$Data);
```